# jquery hide not taking parameter

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="updatePlayerList">
//some content
</div>
```

my code is like this

```
<script>
    $('#updatePlayerList').fadeOut(1000);
</script>
```

Problem is it hides immediately with out waiting for 1000millisecond( like a fade effect)

**SOLVED:**

Problem was with prototype and jquery conflict
found a solution here:
[Problem jQuery and Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024967/problem-jquery-and-prototype)

Comment: Not to sound silly but why are you using `{ }` ?

Comment: i want a fadeout kind of effect here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be wrong. It should be `(` `)` not `{` `}`

```
$('#updatePlayerList').hide(1000); //takes 1000 ms to hide
```

Docs : http://api.jquery.com/hide/

`.hide( duration, [ callback ] )`

If you want to wait a while before hiding, you should use `delay()`

```
$('#updatePlayerList').delay(1000).hide(400);//waits 1000ms to before hiding. Then takes 400ms to hide
```

Delay : http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: i don't want delay i just want a fade effect

Comment: What do you mean `something like this`? Is it or is it not, what you are looking for?

Comment: If it's working in the fiddle, the code is correct. So it's likely something wrong at your end

Comment: try setting up your page in jsfiddle.net and post it in your question.

Comment: i found the source of the problem

Comment: i am importing prototype.js  (if i remove this it works find)
but i need prototype.js for Ajax call... what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery `.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) takes two (optional) parameters, a **duration** and a callback function. The parameter you're passing is not the time jQuery will wait to execute the effect, it is the duration of the effect